# What are some useful Stack Exchange Data Explorer queries for this site?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

During a discussion in chat, the question came up if there were any particularly useful SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) queries for this stack.

Comment: +1. This could be another good candidate for the [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: There are a few queries in other questions with the [meta-tag:data-explorer] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Posts

- [Find questions to reopen](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/461511): Some of these questions should probably be reopened.

## Tags

- [Most common tags with short, long, or missing excerpt or wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/445925): You can browse tag wikis by tweaking the first four parameters on this query.
- [Related tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/459569): Browse the full list of related tags for any tag.
- [Search posts with a specific post type ID](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/476081): Mainly useful for searching tag wikis.
- [Tags with the most views per question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/502270): See which tags are most likely to get views.

## Users

- [Users with the same display name](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/472703): Find all of M.A. Golding’s posts, for example.
- [My reputation graph](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/220825): Cool, but it doesn’t consider the rep cap.

## Other stuff

- [Search comments or view top comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/476438): Find the most popular comments on the site, or search comments by user or by content.
- [Get all review tasks for a specific post ID or user's posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/464985): Fill in the user ID or post ID, and browse old review tasks.
- [Find all questions sucessfully migrated away from a site](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/472000?Site=scifi): See what questions migrated away from here are still open. Click a site name in the results to see each question found.

## Bonus round

- This isn’t a data.SE query, but it’s a data dump: [Reputation audit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation). View your reputation changes, excluding deleted posts. More information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).
- The truly curious can browse my list of [favorite queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/21693?order_by=favorite).

<sub>This has nothing to do with browsing data, but check out the [hidden features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211) of Stack Exchange.</sub>

Comment: For even more cool stuff, see my [favorite Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/users/33178/armadillo?tab=favorites).

Answer (score 2):

[Drive by Idents](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/430740/drive-by-idents)

This is an overview of all questions by a user who has asked just a single question, with a breakdown in identification requests and other questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Votes over time for a specific question and its answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/83159/votes-over-time-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers)

Input a question ID and go to the Graph tab to get a visualisation of how the score of that question and all its answers have changed over time.

Answer (score 0):

[Tags used more than once without a tag wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/432081/tags-used-more-than-once-without-a-wiki).

The title says it all, these are tags that have been used more than once on a post, but have either no excerpt, no wiki, or neither.

Comment: `WikiPostId` will never be `NULL` when `ExcerptPostId` exists. Lots of tags have no wiki that don't show up in that query. I'm biased, but I like [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/445925/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki) better for searching tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding images without alt text**

This is a query to find the [top 15,000 posts that contain images with no alt text](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1442948/top-15k-posts-with-images-that-need-a-description-have-enter-image-description), excluding closed questions (although not answers to closed questions).

This is part of an effort to slowly make the site more accessible by including alt text for images.

[This variation](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1442961/posts-with-multiple-answers-with-no-alt-text) finds questions with multiple answers that have images with no alt text (credit to @AncientSwordRage).

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/127297/my-posts-containing-default-alt-text) allows you to enter your user ID to find your posts that contain inaccessible images.