# How many tags lack tag excerpts?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

On the main site, we have over 2200 tags, at 36 tags a page and 63 pages. The majority of them have at least a tag excerpt, if not a tag wiki. However, there are a decent number without either. Counting the number of tags without an excerpt manually would be cumbersome. Is there any way to determine how many tags lack excerpts?

Comment: I thought you said **experts**

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Nah, that’s most of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SEDE to the rescue! **[Most common tags with short, long, or missing excerpt or wiki](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/445925/most-common-tags-with-short-long-or-missing-excerpt-or-wiki)** - you can tweak the input parameters as desired.

<sub>Thanks to [@amaranth](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9504/31394) for the link.</sub>

Comment: That query looks familiar...

Comment: @amaranth And I credited you! :-)

Comment: That name looks familiar too...