# What other names from Tolkien's Legendarium are often misspelled?

Tags: discussion, editing, data-explorer

I've created [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1554501/misspelled-silmarillion) to find posts that misspell *Silmarillion* or *Silmaril*. It seems we've corrected most of them now. *(I think DavidW deserves a mention here, who has done a lot of these corrections.)*

I'll add the query to [our compendium of useful queries](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9496/19561) to keep an eye on any future misspellings, but I would like to expand it a little to include other common misspellings as well.

**What other names from *Tolkien's Legendarium* are often misspelled?**

Also, do we want to include missed accents? *As wë all know, Tolkíen úses a lot.*

Comment: Tolkien habitually misspells *dwarfs*, does that count?

Comment: Why focus on this specifically and not just common typos in English regardless of post contents? If you are looking for pointless busy-work there's plenty out there for sure.

Comment: @Amarth any user can fix typos, while fixing the spelling of proper nouns can only be done by a user having knowledge of _that_ specific domain, so a typo is likely to be quickly rectified as soon as the question/answer gets some views, while a misspelled name could survive much longer. Moreover, if a name is "only" missing the proper accents even knowledgeable user could deem it "good enough", or they could be unsure of the right accents, or lacking an easy way to enter the proper characters (if they are reading from a mobile phone, for example).

Comment: @lfurini So what you are saying between the lines is that we should focus on name typos that only a few nerds actually care about before fixing English typos and grammar making a post hard to understand for _everyone_?

Comment: @Amarth not at all, and I apologize if my comment sounded elitist! My point is that this type of query can be useful to easily find and fix misspelling that could otherwise go unnoticed for a long time, so it has some merit; such an approach wouldn't help fixing recurring English errors (for example "it's" instead of "its" or viceversa), but for those there are many more eyes around (personally, I try to fix them whenever I see them, even when it's only a 1-character edit).

Answer (score 9):

Candidates so far (other then *Silmaril* / *Silmarillion*):

- Barad-dûr (found: [Baradur](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=baradur), [Barad Ur](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22barad%20ur%22))
- Dol Guldur (found: [Dol Guldor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dol%20guldor%22))
- dwarf (found: [dwarve](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dwarve%22), wearer of scarve)
- Eärendil (found: [Erendil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=erendil))
- Ilúvatar (found: "[Illuvatar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=illuvatar)")
- Khuzdul (found: [Khudzul](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=khudzul), vine of the Khazâd)
- Lothlórien (found: Lothorien)
- Maedhros (found: [Maedros](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=maedros), but note that "Maidros" was the spelling in *Lost Tales*)
- Númenórean (found: ["Numenorian"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=numenorian))
- Saruman (found: ["Sauruman"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btolkiens-legendarium%5D+sauruman), the Green, the Lizard-tamer)
- Sauron (found: [Suaron](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=suaron), lord of Nimesulide)
- Tolkien (found: ["Tolkein"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=tolkein); thanks [Loong](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60449625#60449625))
- Galadriel (found: ["Galadrial"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Galadrial))

Comment: Only 8 examples of Tolk**ei**n. I'm tempted to just fix them all

Comment: @Valorum The idea is to keep an eye on future misspellings as well.

Comment: Fair enough. If there's a single search that can be done to find all of them in one go, that would seem worthwhile.

Comment: _One Search to rule them all, One Search to find them, One Search to fix them all and in the edit history hide them._

Comment: "Middle Earth" is also one I see every now and then

Comment: I think "Middle Earth" is an acceptable spelling variation—Tolkien uses it in a footnote to letter 183. Also "Gilgalad" which Tolkien uses in letter 131.

Comment: Even Tolkien wrote `Baraddur` in some manuscripts. I would guess he was being hasty in writing, as he was prone to do.

Comment: @Valorum The digital Tolkien project has something like 980-ish named characters in it. Good luck with that single search...

Comment: @DavidRoberts _burárum_

Answer (score 2):

I've just corrected, twice, (in comments; there aren't enough extra letters for the software to accept an edit) the misspelling *entlings*. Of course there's no letter "L". Their name is *entings*.